# Build error when using static inner class

Tags: java, android, class, static, inner-classes

I am developing a library for Android and I keep getting a strange error about a static inner class when I use it in a sample project : "cannot find symbol variable":

*This is my factored code :*

**Outer.java** (SDK project)

```
public class Outer {

    [...] // Attributes and methods

    public static class Inner {
        public static int x = 42; 
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java** (Sample project)

```
import com.xxx.xxx.Outer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    [...] // Attributes

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("MainActivity", "x = " + Outer.Inner.x);
    }
}
```

*This is the log error :*

> .../sample/MainActivity.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
>          Log.d("MainActivity", "x = " + Outer.Inner.x);
>                                         ^
>    symbol:   variable Inner
>    location: class Outer

I've another case into my SDK :

My class "ImageHelper" has a static inner class "Builder".

I use it into my SDK and it works, but when I want to use it in the sample project, I've the same error at build runtime.

Is there an error in my code ?

Comment: Strange, works here. Did you clean your build? Here is an answer with some hints and tricks... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Comment: your code seems to be OK. show us your real code. Try to rebuild your project.

Comment: Yes, i clean et rebuild again and again ^^'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to compile your own cut code? It works fine when I do compilation on my own. Maybe it (provided cut) works for you too and your full program uses different class?

Based on your code

```
import com.xxx.xxx.Outer;
```

and absence line for package in the Outer code it is possible that your project has not one Outer but many and one of them has no inner static class.